# Как при наличии нескольких форм, использовать данные из ячейки одного datagridview в ячейках другой datagridview, который находится на другой форме?

Tags: c#, winforms

Много плохого кода. Итак, есть 3 формы. Меню->Входные Данные и Расчёт рейтинга.

***Меню скриншот:***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Входные данные скриншот:***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Рейтинг скриншот:***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём собственно проблема. Во 2 форме (Входные данные) нужно вытянуть несколько ячеек из ДатаГрид и использовать в формулах в ДатаГриде Формы 3. Читал вот [эти](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread110436.html#a_Q2) способы. Пробовал через класс, но там через гетер, сетер идёт сохранение одного значения, а мне нужно хранить желательно массив значений. Пробовал через свойство "родитель", но почему-то постоянно передаёт null.

```
//Вторая форма, когда на ней была кнопка перехода в 3 форму
if(Application.OpenForms.Count=3){
Form f = new Application.OpenForms[1];
f.Owner = this;
f.Show();
this.Hide();
}else{
Rozrah f = new Rozrah();
f.Owner = this;
f.Show();
this.Hide();
}
//Третья форма
Vhidni_Dani main = this.Owner as Vhidni_Dani;
if(main != null)
{
    //сюда не попадал ибо был null
}
```

В итоге решил сделать элементы public и обращаться к ним напрямую. То есть:

```
//Форма 3
    Vhidni_Dani f = new Vhidni_Dani();
                    string w =  Convert.ToString(f.dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value);
```

Если я правильно помню, то таким образом я создаю новый экземпляр формы 2. То есть, если я из меню зайду в данные и изменю их, то новые значения не перейдут в 3 форму. (Также пока что не реализована функция сохранения измененных ячеек, в основной массив данных).

Прошу помочь в проблеме с корректным переносом данных. Любая помощь приветствуется. Код прилагается ниже.

**Меню код:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace ProjectOnSharp
{

    public partial class Menu : Form
    {

        public Menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bttn_vhidni_dani(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                Vhidni_Dani f = new Vhidni_Dani();
                f.Left = this.Left;
                f.Top = this.Top;
                f.Show();
                this.Hide();

        }

        private void bttn_rozrah(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                Rozrah f = new Rozrah();
                f.Left = this.Left;
                f.Top = this.Top;
                f.Show();
                this.Hide();

        }

        private void bttn_exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Данные код:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectOnSharp
{

    public partial class Vhidni_Dani : Form
    {
        string[,] def = new string[73, 2] { //массив данных по умолчанию };
        string[,] cur = new string[73, 2] { //текущий массив данных };

        public Vhidni_Dani()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "На початок звітного року";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "На кінець звітного періоду";

            //label1.Text = cur[0, 0];

            string[] row1 = new string[] { "АКТИВ" };
            string[] row2 = new string[] { "I. НЕОБОРОТНІ АКТИВИ"};
            string[] row3 = new string[] { "Нематеріальні активи", cur[0, 0], cur[0, 1] };
            string[] row4 = new string[] { "Основні засоби", cur[1,0], cur[1, 1] };
            string[] row5 = new string[] { "Незавершене будівництво", cur[2, 0], cur[2, 1] };
            //кусок кода убран для экономия места
            string[] row94 = new string[] { "Скоригований чистий прибуток (збиток) на акцію", "0", "0" };


            object[] rows = new object[] {
                row1,- row94};

            //Заполняем таблицу без подсчитываемых значений (статические данные)
            foreach (string[] rowArray in rows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowArray);
            }

            //Создаём и инициализируем вспомогательные переменные, для подсчитываемых значений
            int temp111, temp112, temp131, temp132, temp311, temp312, temp321, temp322, temp381, temp382, temp451, temp452, temp501, temp502, temp641, temp642, temp651, temp652, temp661, temp662, temp731, temp732, temp761, temp762, temp851, temp852, temp901, temp902;
            temp111 = temp112 = temp131 = temp132 = temp311 = temp312 = temp321 = temp322 = temp381 = temp382 = temp451 = temp452 = temp501 = temp502 = temp641 = temp642 = temp651 = temp652 = temp661 = temp662 = temp731 = temp732 = temp761 = temp762 = temp851 = temp852 = temp901 = temp902 = 0;

            //Вычисляем подсчитываемые значения
            for (int i = 2; i < 10;i++ )
            {
                temp111 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                temp112 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            }

            for (int i = 14; i < 22; i++)
            {
                temp131 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                temp132 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            }

            temp311 = Convert.ToInt32(temp131) 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[22].Cells[1].Value) 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[23].Cells[1].Value) 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[25].Cells[1].Value) 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[27].Cells[1].Value) 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[28].Cells[1].Value) 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[29].Cells[1].Value);

            temp312 = Convert.ToInt32(temp132)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[22].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[23].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[25].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[27].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[28].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[29].Cells[2].Value);

            temp321 = temp111 + temp311;
            temp322 = temp112 + temp312;

            temp381 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[39].Cells[1].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[41].Cells[1].Value);
            temp382 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[39].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[41].Cells[2].Value);

            temp451 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[34].Cells[1].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[36].Cells[1].Value) 
                    + temp381 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[42].Cells[1].Value) 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[43].Cells[1].Value);

            temp452 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[34].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[36].Cells[2].Value)
                    + temp382
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[42].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[43].Cells[2].Value);

            for (int i = 47; i < 50; i++)
            {
                temp501 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                temp502 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            }

            temp641 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[51].Cells[1].Value) 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[52].Cells[1].Value) 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[59].Cells[1].Value) 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[60].Cells[1].Value) 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[61].Cells[1].Value) 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[62].Cells[1].Value);

            temp642 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[51].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[52].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[59].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[60].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[61].Cells[2].Value)
                    + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[62].Cells[2].Value);

            temp651 = temp451 
                    + temp501 
                    + temp641;

            temp652 = temp452
                    + temp502
                    + temp642;

            temp661 = temp651 - temp321;
            temp662 = temp652 - temp322;

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------

            if ((          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[1].Value) 
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[1].Value))) 
                >= 0)
            {
                temp731 =          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[1].Value) 
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[1].Value));
            } else
            {
                temp731 = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[1].Value) 
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[1].Value)));
            }

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------

            if ((          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[1].Value) 
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[1].Value)))
                >= 0)
            {
                temp732 =          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[2].Value) 
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[2].Value));
            }
            else
            {
                temp732 = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[2].Value) 
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[2].Value)));
            }

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------

            if ((          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[1].Value) 
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[1].Value)) 
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[73].Cells[1].Value)) 
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[74].Cells[1].Value))) 
                >= 0)
            {
                temp761 =          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[1].Value) 
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[1].Value)) 
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[73].Cells[1].Value)) 
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[74].Cells[1].Value));
            }
            else
            {
                temp761 = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[1].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[1].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[73].Cells[1].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[74].Cells[1].Value)));
            }

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------

            if ((          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[2].Value) 
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[2].Value))
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[73].Cells[2].Value))
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[74].Cells[2].Value)))
                >= 0)
            {
                temp762 =          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[2].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[2].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[73].Cells[2].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[74].Cells[2].Value));
            }
            else
            {
                temp762 = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[2].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[2].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[73].Cells[2].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[74].Cells[2].Value)));
            }

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------

            if ((          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[1].Value)
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[1].Value))
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[73].Cells[1].Value))
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[74].Cells[1].Value))
                +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[77].Cells[1].Value)
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[78].Cells[1].Value))
                +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[79].Cells[1].Value)
                +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[80].Cells[1].Value)
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[81].Cells[1].Value))
                +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[82].Cells[1].Value)
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[83].Cells[1].Value)))
                >= 0)
            {
                temp851 =         Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[1].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[1].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[73].Cells[1].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[74].Cells[1].Value))
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[77].Cells[1].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[78].Cells[1].Value))
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[79].Cells[1].Value)
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[80].Cells[1].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[81].Cells[1].Value))
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[82].Cells[1].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[83].Cells[1].Value));
            }
            else
            {
                temp851 = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[1].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[1].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[73].Cells[1].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[74].Cells[1].Value))
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[77].Cells[1].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[78].Cells[1].Value))
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[79].Cells[1].Value)
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[80].Cells[1].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[81].Cells[1].Value))
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[82].Cells[1].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[83].Cells[1].Value)));
            }

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------

            if ((          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[2].Value)
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[2].Value))
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[73].Cells[2].Value))
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[74].Cells[2].Value))
                +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[77].Cells[2].Value)
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[78].Cells[2].Value))
                +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[79].Cells[2].Value)
                +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[80].Cells[2].Value)
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[81].Cells[2].Value))
                +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[82].Cells[2].Value)
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[83].Cells[2].Value)))
                >= 0)
            {
                temp852 =          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[2].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[2].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[73].Cells[2].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[74].Cells[2].Value))
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[77].Cells[2].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[78].Cells[2].Value))
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[79].Cells[2].Value)
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[80].Cells[2].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[81].Cells[2].Value))
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[82].Cells[2].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[83].Cells[2].Value));
            }
            else
            {
                temp852 = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[70].Cells[2].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[71].Cells[2].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[73].Cells[2].Value))
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[74].Cells[2].Value))
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[77].Cells[2].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[78].Cells[2].Value))
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[79].Cells[2].Value)
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[80].Cells[2].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[81].Cells[2].Value))
                        +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[82].Cells[2].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[83].Cells[2].Value)));
            }

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------

            if ((          temp851
                +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[85].Cells[1].Value)
                +          Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[86].Cells[1].Value)
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[87].Cells[1].Value)))
                >= 0)
            {
                temp901 = temp851
                        + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[85].Cells[1].Value)
                        + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[86].Cells[1].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[87].Cells[1].Value));
            }
            else
            {
                temp901 = Math.Abs(temp851
                        + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[85].Cells[1].Value)
                        + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[86].Cells[1].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[87].Cells[1].Value)));
            }

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------

            if ((temp852
                + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[85].Cells[2].Value)
                + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[86].Cells[2].Value)
                - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[87].Cells[2].Value)))
                >= 0)
            {
                temp902 = temp852
                        + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[85].Cells[2].Value)
                        + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[86].Cells[2].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[87].Cells[2].Value));
            }
            else
            {
                temp902 = Math.Abs(temp852
                        + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[85].Cells[2].Value)
                        + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[86].Cells[2].Value)
                        - Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[87].Cells[2].Value)));
            }

            //Переопределяем и заносим в таблицу подсчитываемые данные
            row11 = new string[] { "РАЗОМ по розділу I", Convert.ToString(temp111), Convert.ToString(temp112) };
            row13 = new string[] { "Запаси", Convert.ToString(temp131), Convert.ToString(temp132) };
            row31 = new string[] { "РАЗОМ по розділу II", Convert.ToString(temp311), Convert.ToString(temp312) };
            row32 = new string[] { "БАЛАНС", Convert.ToString(temp321), Convert.ToString(temp322) };
            row38 = new string[] { "Резервний капітал", Convert.ToString(temp381), Convert.ToString(temp382) };
            row45 = new string[] { "РАЗОМ по розділу III", Convert.ToString(temp451), Convert.ToString(temp452) };
            row50 = new string[] { "РАЗОМ за розділом IV", Convert.ToString(temp501), Convert.ToString(temp502) };
            row64 = new string[] { "РАЗОМ по розділу V", Convert.ToString(temp641), Convert.ToString(temp642) };
            row65 = new string[] { "БАЛАНС", Convert.ToString(temp651), Convert.ToString(temp652) };
            row66 = new string[] { "Перевірка балансу", Convert.ToString(temp661), Convert.ToString(temp662) };
            row73 = new string[] { "Валовий прибуток", Convert.ToString(temp731), Convert.ToString(temp732) };
            row76 = new string[] { "Прибуток (збиток) від продажу", Convert.ToString(temp761), Convert.ToString(temp762) };
            row85 = new string[] { "Прибуток (збиток) до оподаткування", Convert.ToString(temp851), Convert.ToString(temp852) };
            row90 = new string[] { "Чистий прибуток (збиток) звітного періоду", Convert.ToString(temp901), Convert.ToString(temp902) };

            rows = new object[] {
                row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10,
                row11, row12, row13, row14, row15, row16, row17, row18, row19, row20,
                row21, row22, row23, row24, row25, row26, row27, row28, row29, row30,
                row31, row32, row33, row34, row35, row36, row37, row38, row39, row40,
                row41, row42, row43, row44, row45, row46, row47, row48, row49, row50,
                row51, row52, row53, row54, row55, row56, row57, row58, row59, row60,
                row61, row62, row63, row64, row65, row66, row67, row68, row69, row70,
                row71, row72, row73, row74, row75, row76, row77, row78, row79, row80,
                row81, row82, row83, row84, row85, row86, row87, row88, row89, row90,
                row91, row92, row93, row94};

            //Очищаем старую таблицу
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            //Заполняем таблицу вместе с подсчитываемыми значениями
            foreach (string[] rowArray in rows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowArray);
            }

            //Запрещаем редактировать первый столбец
            for (int i = 0;i<rows.Length;i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }

        private void bttn_menu(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form f = Application.OpenForms[0];
            f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            f.Left = this.Left;
            f.Top = this.Top;
            f.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

    }
}
```

**Код Рейтинг:**

```
namespace ProjectOnSharp
{
    public partial class Rozrah : Form
    {
        public Rozrah()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

                Vhidni_Dani f = new Vhidni_Dani();
                string w =  Convert.ToString(f.dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value);


            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "На початок звітного року";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "На кінець звітного періоду";

            string[] row1 = new string[] { w };


            object[] rows = new object[] {
                row1};

            //Заполняем таблицу без подсчитываемых значений (статические данные)
            foreach (string[] rowArray in rows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowArray);
            }

        }

        private void bttn_menu(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form f = Application.OpenForms[0];
            f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            f.Left = this.Left;
            f.Top = this.Top;
            f.Show();
            //this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В вашем вопросе нет пояснения по какому же принципу идет выбор ячеек во входных данных. По клику юзера на нужной ячейке? Или как? И нужно ли предварительно проверять входные данные, вдруг юзер выбрал не ту ячейку? Да, и не совсем понятно, можно ли выбирать несколько ячее или только по одиночке.

Comment: @Bulson выбор ячеек куда? В Грид в 3 форму? Если да, то они статические. Юзер по идее ничего не выбирает, возможно в дальнейшем может редактировать грид. То есть я заранее знаю, что к примеру:из второй формы из ячейки[15,20] нужно забрать значение и поставить в ячейку[5.,5] в форму 3. Если вы не об этом, а о том когда считывать данные в 3 форму, то желательно при загрузке 3 формы.

Comment: @Bulson видимо я не так выразился. (Откорректировал вопрос). Главная задача, не то чтобы пользователь ВЫБРАЛ ячейки которые, будут использоваться во 2 датаГриде, а в том что при наличии данных в 1 датагриде, некоторые из них СРАЗУ ЖЕ(или при загрузке 3 формы со 2 датаГридом) использовались И во 2 датаГриде. Если есть ещё вопросы, обращайтесь)

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно так сделать

```
DataTable Table = new DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = new Person().Persons();
        }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Table.AsDataView();
                if (Table.Columns.Count == 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
                    {
                        Table.Columns.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText, typeof(string));
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var values = new List<object>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                    {
                        values.Add(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value);
                    }
                    Table.Rows.Add(values.ToArray());
                }
                new Form2(Table).ShowDialog();
            }
```

Второй форме сделать так

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(DataTable row)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = row;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ахда там во втормо окне добавление идет. Надо очичать список если надо коненчо